# Handle Error from normal function in Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, error-handling

I use a code to verify if the jwt in expired or not ( from angular2-jwt ).
But if the user change the value of token in localStorage, for ex:
id_token => "123", it show a error and stop the app.
but, I want to handle this error in Guard.

//Error:

```
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: JWT must have 3 parts
Error: JWT must have 3 parts
```

How can I handle this error in Guard, if the throw is fired?

//Guard.ts:

```
 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean>|boolean
 {

          if (this.tokenService.isTokenExpired(token)) {
              this.auth.loggedIn = false;
              this.loginService.logout();
              this.notifications.success = false;
              this.notifications.status = 401;
              this.notifications.state = 'alertFail';
              this.notifications.message = 'Token Expirado! Faça o login novamente.';
              this.notifications.arrayError = [];
              this.notifications2.setNotifications(this.notifications);
              this.router.navigate(['/login']);
              return false;
          }

      return true;
      }
```

//One of the functions:

```
public decodeToken(token: string): any {
        let parts = token.split('.');

        if (parts.length !== 3) {
            throw new Error('JWT must have 3 parts');
        }

        let decoded = this.urlBase64Decode(parts[1]);
        if (!decoded) {
            throw new Error('Cannot decode the token');
        }

        return JSON.parse(decoded);
    }
```

Comment: I guess I am little confused at what you are trying to accomplish. Is the guard not functioning properly? 

Honestly the best way to verify a token is to send it back to an API that can verify it through and through. If your app can decode the token, then you have lost any security you had in using tokens to verify identity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a try/catch block is what you are after:

```
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean>|boolean
     {
         try {
              if (this.tokenService.isTokenExpired(token)) {
                  this.auth.loggedIn = false;
                  this.loginService.logout();
                  this.notifications.success = false;
                  this.notifications.status = 401;
                  this.notifications.state = 'alertFail';
                  this.notifications.message = 'Token Expirado! Faça o login novamente.';
                  this.notifications.arrayError = [];
                  this.notifications2.setNotifications(this.notifications);
                  this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                  return false;
              }
            }
          catch (e) {
             return false;
          }
          return true;
 }
```